# Should I use fileName or filePath to describe a fully qualified file name in .NET?

Tags: .net

I have a method to read a file, the parameter should be the fully qualified file name.
The code I have uses fileName, filePath, or path randomly.

> void ReadSomeFile(String fileName);
>   void ReadSomeFile(String filePath);
>   void ReadSomeFile(String path);

The .net method "File.Exists(string path)" uses path, but "FileDialog.FileName" uses fileName.
Which name do you suggest to use?

Comment: I think filePath makes it clear that you want the complete path where as FileName can be confusing as in whether you need just the name or the full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, personally, would use `filePath`, as it's the most explicit.

That being said, whatever you choose, I would make sure that your documentation explicitly states that you require the fully qualified file name with path, if that is required by your method.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could consider using class to store your paths and follow unit pattern, so that you will always know what part of path your object is storing, or you can fetch from it properties like fullPath, filename, directoryPath, etc..

Somethig like this:

```
public class PathStorage
{
    private string path;
    private PathTypeEnum pathType;

    public PathStorage(string path, PathTypeEnum pathType)
    {
       this.path = path;
       this.pathType = pathType;
    }

    public string GetFullPath() {
    ...
    }

    public string GetFilename() {
    ...
    }
}
```

or even better combine that with state design pattern.

Comment: Your class is badly written. `GetFullPath` and `GetFilename` should be properties(dropping `Get` of course). Your enum definition is missing, and the enum name should be upper case.

Comment: The thing is that this question is rather generic, not .net specific (although it's marked as that) and properties would make it c# specific which IMHO it is not. Enum definition is missing, because it is just solution idea, not a complete solution. Agreed on upper case for enum, my bad here. Also in real code you would like to avoid adding enum suffix to type name.

Answer (score 0):

Usually filePath is the full path to the file, e.g. C:\tmp\foo.txt, while fileName is just the name of the file plus extension, in this case foo.txt.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree about filePath being a safer option. Should you ever reuse the class in a different library or application, it can help insure the path to the file remains steady.